# Maximum size of objects that can be stored in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone

Can anyone please tell me the maximum size of NSUserDefaults. Means objects or primitives we can store in userdefaults. for example 10 MB etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

No, there is no size limit to NSUserDefaults, aside from the storage capacity of the device itself.

see [NSUserDefaults storage size capacity](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1763096?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact value, but NSUserDefaults are meant to store a small amount of data, I think the maximum is in the order of the kilobytes.

If you want to store bigger property lists, then consider storing them in their own files.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can anyone know the exact size?

Comment: Take a look at this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1763096?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: you are uninformed and propagate erroneous information. If you don't know the answer, don't answer...