# Swift ios how many strings and how big can I save using UserDefaults.standard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wonder how many and how big strings I can save using `UserDefaults.standard`

Eg:

```
static func saveUsername(_ token: String) {
        userDefaults.set(token, forKey: "username")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

I want to save my users: username, email, address(state,city,street), first name, last name

But I am not sure how big/how many strings I can save or what kind of impact it has on my app storing many strings

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults You can save tens of megabytes of data. It's just a file.

Comment: Keep in mind that UserDefaults is just a file, so it needs to read and write the whole thing whenever you do anything with it. You don't want it to get too big.

Comment: To add to previous comments, if it's too big, you need to use core data.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262654/maximum-size-of-objects-that-can-be-stored-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Recommended reading https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: You *can* save as much as you want, but you should **not**. The bigger the file is, the slower the defaults sync is. This is meant for storing tiny values. For anything else than a few text/numerical values, use proper storage, not defaults.